# Getting No bean named defined while implementing storage extension in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, tridion-storage-extension

I am trying to implement the storage extension using below example,

http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-1.aspx

I created my DAO and other files with the same name used in above example. After creating these files I build my code using eclipse and coverted it into .JAR file name (cd_search_Indexer).

1) I copied my jar file to my presentation tridion_home/lib folder

2) I created bundle xml with name search_dao_bundle.xml as below and placed on same location i.e. tridion_home/config where my cd_storage_xml is placed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StorageDAOBundles>
    <StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="PublishAction" class="com.tridion.storage.extension.search.JPAPublishActionDAO" />
    </StorageDAOBundle>
</StorageDAOBundles>
```

3) After that I added my bundle entries into my cd_storage_conf.xml as below:

```
<StorageBindings>
    <Bundle src="search_dao_bundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>
```

and down under I created my new storage type as below:

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="searchdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="********" />
        <!--Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" /-->
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="********" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="********" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="********" />
    </DataSource>
</Storage>
```

After that for itemmapping I did below

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false"> 
    <Item typeMapping="PublishAction" cached="false" storageId="searchdb" />
</ItemTypes>
```

4) I restarted my deployer service got below exception in my core logs

```
2013-01-03 12:44:20,713 ERROR JPADAOFactory - Unable to load JPA DAO with name: PublishAction and class: com.tridion.storage.extension.search.JPAPublishActionDAO due too exception in DAO construction
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'JPAPublishActionDAO' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory.configureBundle(JPADAOFactory.java:80) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:91) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:65) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:51) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:139) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:106) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:86) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:58) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:90) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:145) [cd_deployer.jar:na]    
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:74) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
```

Edit:
Below are the steps I followed to create my DAO, Entity and Interface classes.

1) Open the eclipse helios

2) Created a project with name "Storage Extension"

3) Created new folder "lib" and added all the tridion_home/lib

4) Created new package "com.tridion.storage.extension.search"

5) Added my DAO, Entity and Interface java classes

6) Added 'lib' jars in reference

7) Build the package converted to jar (cd_storage_indexer)

8) copied the build jar into tridion_home/lib

9) Rest followed the same as Mihai has suggested.

Comment: I _think_ I had the same issue before and it was because of an option in Eclipse. Decorators marked with the @ sign like @Component("JPAPublishActionDAO") or @Scope("prototype") were not included in the Exported JAR (I found this out after decompiling my own jar) and therefore Spring choked on it. Can't remember what it was, but it was one of the options in the Export as Jar dialog

Comment: If you have access to the Forum: https://forum.tridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7078 - I'll post it as an answer giving credit where it's due

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tridion Forum user Pankaj Gaur ran into the [same issue](https://forum.tridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7078) before.

> We need to create the class file carefully when we are exporting them as JAR from Eclipse.
>   To pin point on the solution:
>   On the First screen while exporting the class file to JAR, make sure "Add Directory Entries" option is checked

Comment: @Nuno...thanks for reply, I tried to build the jar using "Add Directory Entries" option checked, I can't find any difference after decompiling it, can you suggest how could I differentiate between  "Add Directory Entries" or without "Add Directory Entries" jars

Comment: Sorry, no. As I said in that post in the forum, I had to experiment with various options until it worked. If you decompile, do you have the @Scope statement in your code? Might also be worth googling...

Comment: Ok....one more things while creating new project do we need to create JPA Project or Just Simple Project as this could cause some issues while creating jars. I have created simple java project and created java package and later three files (DAO, ENtity and Interface)

Comment: I used a WAR project (imported a working WAR file with Tridion jars), and then just created a class inside it. This allows me to run Tridion "inside" Eclipse.

Comment: is there any blogs for this...where I can see implementation using tridion jars

Comment: On this page I cover how to load a deployer in Eclipse: http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-3.aspx (pretty much the same as a normal Tridion webapp), Jaime also covers how to setup tomcat & eclipse: http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/adding-tomcat-application-server-to.html and Tridion ships various pre-built WAR files as part of the installation package

Answer (score 3):

Your type mapping is wrong:

```
<StorageDAO typeMapping="PublishAction" ...
```

Each type mapping maps an existing item type to a (built-in or custom) DAO for that type. A `PublishAction` is not a built-in item type and I doubt you intended to store those.

Most likely you are looking to replace one of the existing item types, such as `Binary` and/or `BinaryVariant` like in Vinod's example.

Comment: @Frank...thanks for reply, well I just followed all the sample code provided by Mihai in above article and tried to populate the table, what could be wrong in the implementation as I am sure <StorageDAO typeMapping="PublishAction" class="com.tridion.storage.extension.search.JPAPublishActionDAO" /> is same as suggested, can you point me any place where could I look

Comment: Have a look at the Binary Event Tracker on SDL Tridion World.

Comment: The type mapping is correct. Indeed it creates a new type, hence the not built-in name. Depending on your needs, it might not be what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have for deployer extension config (cd_storage_conf)..

listing one then that one will be used for that publication unless it is overwriten on a lower level.
 If storage defined by storageId does not exist then default storage defined by ItemTypes element will be used unless lower level type mappings are not matched.

```
<Publication Id="000" defaultStorageId="TridionDB" cached="false">
  <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" storageId="defaultCdnFile" cached="false" /> 
  <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultCdnFile" cached="false" /> 
  </Publication>


<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.extensions.storage.XXX.CDNFSDAOFactory" Id="defaultCdnFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
  <Root Path="X:\XXXXX\DeployerExtension" /> 
  <Mapping PublicationId="50" BaseURL="http://XXX.com" /> 
  <Akamai Username="xxxx" Password="xxxx" /> 
  <Setting Property="https.proxyHost" Value="xxxx" /> 
  <Setting Property="https.proxyPort" Value="0000" /> 
  <Setting Property="https.proxyUser" Value="xxxx" /> 
  <Setting Property="https.proxyPassword" Value="xxxx" /> 
  <Setting Property="https.proxyDomain" Value="xx" /> 
  <Setting Property="proxySet" Value="true" /> 
  </Storage>
```

Thanks
Vin

Comment: thanks for reply, I am not sure using directly the class in storage node Class="com.tridion.extensions.storage.XXX.CDNFSDAOFactory", instead of that I we need to put <StorageBindings>
    <Bundle src="search_dao_bundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>
Please suggest whether we can directly use the class

Comment: Works with StorageBindings , no probs. Thanks Vin

Answer (score 0):

After few RND and suggestions given by Tridion Experts above, I finally managed to load my BEAN.

Instead of building JAR from eclipse, I tried to build it from Command Prompt (CMD).

Go to the bin directrory of your project and write below command over there

```
jar -cvf cd_storage_extensions.jar *
```

Thanks to all of the experts (Nuno, Frank and Vinod).

Comment: Indeed that was the only way for me too to get the right JAR created. I don't know why eclipse chokes on the empty directories, but it does...